# MPI debugging Segmentation fault

Tags: c, debugging, mpi

I'm trying to sort an array of random numbers using Odd- Even transposition but I keep getting a segmentation error when running my code:

```
[islb:48966] *** Process received signal ***
[islb:48966] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[islb:48966] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[islb:48966] Failing at address: 0x28
[islb:48966] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf810)[0x7fc3da4cb810]
[islb:48966] [ 1] /lib64/libc.so.6(memcpy+0xa3)[0x7fc3da1c7cf3]
[islb:48966] [ 2] /usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.so.6(opal_convertor_unpack+0x10b)[0x7fc3d9c372db]
[islb:48966] [ 3] /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so(mca_pml_ob1_recv_request_progress_match+0x138)[0x7fc3d58507a8]
[islb:48966] [ 4] /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so(mca_pml_ob1_recv_req_start+0x1b1)[0x7fc3d5850d11]
[islb:48966] [ 5] /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so(mca_pml_ob1_recv+0x139)[0x7fc3d5849489]
[islb:48966] [ 6] /usr/local/lib/libmpi.so.1(MPI_Recv+0xc0)[0x7fc3da742f40]
[islb:48966] [ 7] oddEven[0x40115a]
[islb:48966] [ 8] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0x7fc3da161c36]
[islb:48966] [ 9] oddEven[0x400c19]
[islb:48966] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 48966 on node islb exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The program allocates the array, it's when it comes to scattering it amongst the processes that the error seems to occur as the print statment directly after the scatter call only prints for process 0 and then prints the error message.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"

const int MAX = 10000;
int myid, numprocs;
int i, n, j, k, arrayChunk, minindex;
int A, B;
int temp;

int swap(int *x, int *y) {
  temp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = temp;
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int* arr = NULL;
  int* value = NULL;
  MPI_Status status;
  //int arr[] = {16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

  srand(time(0));
  time_t t1, t2;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);

  if (myid == 0) {
    printf("Enter the number of elements you would like in the array \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    arrayChunk = n/numprocs;
    //printf("cpus: %d, #s per cpu: %d\n", numprocs, arrayChunk);

    //Allocate memory for the array
    arr = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    value = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    // Generate an array of size n random numbers and prints them
    printf("Elements in the array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      arr[i] = (rand() % 100) + 1;
      printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    time(&t1);
  }

  if ((n % numprocs) != 0) {
    if (myid == 0)
      printf("Number of Elements are not divisible by numprocs \n");
    MPI_Finalize();
    return(0);
  }

  // Broadcast the size of each chunk
  MPI_Bcast(&arrayChunk, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Scatter(&arr, arrayChunk, MPI_INT, &value, arrayChunk, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  printf("Processor %d receives %d\n", myid, value[0]);

  for (i = 0; i < numprocs; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      if (myid%2 == 0) {
        MPI_Send(&value[0], arrayChunk, MPI_INT, myid + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&value[arrayChunk], arrayChunk, MPI_INT, myid + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        for (j = 0; j < (arrayChunk * 2 - 1); j++) {
          minindex = j;
          for (k = j + 1; k < arrayChunk * 2; k++) {
            if (value[k] < value[minindex]) {
              minindex = k;
            }
          }
          if (minindex > j) {
            swap(&value[j], &value[minindex]);
          }
        }
        //printf("myid %d i: %d, %d\n", myid, i, value[0]);
      } else {
        MPI_Recv(&value[arrayChunk], arrayChunk, MPI_INT, myid - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Send(&value[0], arrayChunk, MPI_INT, myid - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        for (j = 0; j < (arrayChunk * 2 - 1); j++) {
          minindex = j;
          for (k = j + 1; k < arrayChunk * 2; k++) {
            if (value[k] < value[minindex]) {
              minindex = k;
            }
          }
          if (minindex > j) {
            swap(&value[j], &value[minindex]);
          }
        }

        for (j = 0; j < arrayChunk; j++) {
         swap(&value[j], &value[j + arrayChunk]);
        }
        //printf("myid %d i: %d, %d\n", myid, i, value[0]);
      }
    } else {
      if ((myid%2 == 1) && (myid != (numprocs-1))) {
        MPI_Send(&value[0], arrayChunk, MPI_INT, myid + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&value[arrayChunk], arrayChunk, MPI_INT, myid + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        for (j = 0; j < (arrayChunk * 2 - 1); j++) {
          minindex = j;
          for (k = j + 1; k < arrayChunk * 2; k++) {
            if (value[k] < value[minindex]) {
              minindex = k;
            }
          }
          if (minindex > j) {
            swap(&value[j], &value[minindex]);
          }
        }
        //printf("myid %d i: %d, %d\n", myid, i, value[0]);
      } else if (myid != 0 && myid != (numprocs-1)) {
        MPI_Recv(&value[arrayChunk], arrayChunk, MPI_INT, myid - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Send(&value[0], 1, MPI_INT, myid - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        for (j = 0; j < (arrayChunk * 2 - 1); j++) {
          minindex = j;
          for (k = j + 1; k < arrayChunk * 2; k++) {
            if (value[k] < value[minindex]) {
              minindex = k;
            }
          }
          if (minindex > j) {
            swap(&value[j], &value[minindex]);
          }
        }

        for (j = 0; j < arrayChunk; j++) {
          swap(&value[j], &value[j + arrayChunk]);
        }
        //printf("myid %d i: %d, %d\n", myid, i, value[0]);
      }
    }
  }

  MPI_Gather(&value[0], arrayChunk, MPI_INT, &arr[0], arrayChunk, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if (myid == 0) {
    time(&t2);
    printf("Sorted array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Time in sec. %f\n", difftime(t2, t1));
  }

  // Free allocated memory
  if (arr != NULL) {
    free(arr);
    arr = NULL;

    free(value);
    value = NULL;
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

I'm not very familiar with C and it could well be that I've used `malloc` and/or addresses and pointers incorrectly, as such it's probably something simple.

Sorry for the amount of code but I thought it would be better to supply all of it to allow for proper debugging.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you provide a _minimal_ example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: this line, inside the swap() function: 'temp = *x;' is using a global variable 'temp'  It would be much better to use a local/auto variable: 'int temp = *x;'  Note: 3 exclusive-or operations would be 1) faster 2) not require any stack space for 'temp'

Comment: this line: arrayChunk = n/numprocs; is performing an integer divide.  If numprocs is larger than the user entered 'n' then the result will always be 0

Comment: the free() function checks for a NULL pointer, so no need for user code to also perform the check

Comment: at this line: 'printf("Enter the number of elements you would like in the array \n");'  the code is not giving the user enough information.  the user needs to know the value of numprocs and that n has to be a multiple of numprocs

Comment: this code block: 'if ((n % numprocs) != 0) {' exits the program, therefore, to avoid a memory leak both the malloc'd memory areas need to be free'd.  Those pointers to allocated memory are 'arr' and 'value'.

Comment: Returned value(s) from malloc and scanf functions should always be checked to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: Discovered that arrayChunk and value were only being declared within process 0 and I didn't broadcast them to the other processes. So with this and the changes suggested above it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `MPI_Scatter` command. You try to scatter the information and store in `value`, but if you look above that code, only rank 0 has allocated any memory for `value`. When any and all other ranks try to store data into `value`, you will get a segmentation fault (and indeed you do). Instead, remove the `value = malloc(...);` line from inside the `if` block, and put it after the `MPI_Bcast` as `value = malloc(arrayChunk * sizeof(int));`. I've not looked through the rest of the code to see if there are any issues elsewhere as well, but that is likely the cause of the initial seg-fault.

Answer (score 0):

I would build program with debugging info (most likely `-g` compile flag), try geting coredump and try using `gdb` debugger to locate the bug. Corefile is created when process crashes and it holds process memory image at the moment of crash.

If after program crash coredump file is not created, You'll need to figure out how to enable it on Your system. You may create simple buggy program (for example with `a=x/0;` or similar error) and play a bit. Coredump may be called `core`, `PID.core` (PID - number of crashed process), or something similar. Sometimes it is enough to set *core file size* tu *unlimited* using `ulimit`. Also check `kernel.core_*` sysctl's on Linux.

Once You have corecump, You can use it with `gdb` or similar debuger (`ddd`):

```
gdb executable_file core
```